# Can I remove the meta tags in github's gists?

Tags: html, github, sass, gist

for Github gists there is a meta tag for the name, "view raw", hosted with <3 by GitHub, when linking to a page.

I was wondering if it was possible to remove that because it makes my site break if any of those links are clicked.

In the scss file

```
gist-embed.scss:56

.gist .gist-meta {
}
```

Is what needs to be removed or hidden.

Comment: How does it make your site break? Those are GitHub's way of advertising in exchange for your use of the Gist service that they provide for free.

Answer (score 1):

```
.gist .gist-meta{
    display: none !important;
}
```

#### Hosted with ♥ by Github